# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error, php-parse-error

recently I have gotten this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/aps/public_html/wp-content/themes/Valor/functions.php on line 54`

I have looked at this line and found no problems, and ran it through a PHP error code finder.

Just to be sure, I copied the code from the functions.php I have saved on my computer
into the editor and it still happens.

I am using wordpress and the Valor theme.

I had been editing these lines when it happened:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { // Added in 2.9
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'game_feature', 1000, 500, true );
    add_image_size( 'story_feature', 150, 100, true );
    add_image_size( 'video_feature', 150, 200, true );
    add_image_size( 'review_thumb', 120, 80, true );
    add_image_size( 'post_image', 660, 350, true );
```

I changed all the 'true' to 'false', because I wanted the thumbnails on my site to fit
into the box, rather than be cropped. This didn't do anything so instead I just took
away 'true' and 'false' entirely, leaving a blank space.

It was after I did this and hit 'save' that the error came up. I quickly went back and changed them all to 'true' in order to undo the error, but from what you can see and from what I have already told you, it didn't work, despite my efforts.

I'm very new to PHP, and the only explanation I can think of is that by deleting those values it caused another .php file to change something, but like I said, I'm new.

Line 54 is: `add_image_size( 'game_feature', 1000, 500, true );`

Comment: did you try again reloading your file as this code seems to be fine.

Comment: Your code is fine. Can you look into other parts of the file?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify, I know that the code is fine. I ran it through a few checks and even copied the original code from the file on my computer onto it, and still no luck.

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/e7yDK9gx

I had to put it in pastebin because it was too long to fit in here.

Comment: on line 13 you have an if statement with no {}.

Comment: change true to 1 and false to 0, the only possiblity i can see is that you made a function called true and that your scripts does expect a '(' Even if the number of arguments in the add_image_size function are not correct, it would not call a parse error.

Comment: That didn't work. The thing is, my site works just fine, I just cannot access my WP admin panel, except for the editor.

OH Guys I just found something.

This whole time I have been in the Editor and assumed it was the only thing that worked. Wrong, I have simply been hitting 'back' every time I attempted to change something, but what was actually happening is that nothing was being submitted, and I was just going back to the already loaded page!

Comment: So, now I will go ahead and manually get into the functions.php through cpanel and apply all of the changes that you guys have told me, and it will probably work, so I shall do that now and tell you.

Comment: It worked! Sorry about that guys, that mistake was very silly, I should have realized. Basically I just copied my original code into it.

But thanks anyway for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On line `13`, you have:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
```

You forgot to put the opening quote at the end - `{`
The line `13` should look like:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
```

**EDIT:**
Don't forget to close the tag on line `31`. `}`

**EDIT 2:**
Try the solution that @DimitriMostrey said in the comments it might work.

> change true to 1 and false to 0, the only possiblity i can see is that
>   you made a function called true and that your scripts does expect a
>   '(' Even if the number of arguments in the add_image_size function are
>   not correct, it would not call a parse error.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working.

Comment: Just to be sure, I made it look like this now:

`/* SIDEBARS */
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

 register_sidebar(array(
 'name' => 'Sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<li class="sidebox %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
 'before_title' => '<h3 class="sidetitl">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
 
    ));

 register_sidebar(array(
 'name' => 'Footer',
 'before_widget' => '<li class="botwid %2$s">',
 'after_widget' => '</li>',
 'before_title' => '<h3 class="bothead">',
 'after_title' => '</h3>',
 ));  
}
`

Comment: I cannot see Dimitris comment. What does it say?

Comment: I put it as a quote in my question.

Answer (score 0):

if you get tired of trying to find/solve the problem (as your code is fine), start from scratch ie active another theme, then delete valor theme, paste unmodified valor theme back, then activate valor theme.

fyi, [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) might help the next time you make a mistake, ctrl+z is good, until you close the file. mistakes are the only way you learn.

Comment: Yeah I might try that, thanks.